# Inserting Timestamp data through jsp page and validating through servlet

Tags: java, database, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm trying to insert data into database through a JSP page and a servlet. I have to store a timestamp value like this :"2016-FEB-12 10:45:22". When I try to enter the data into the database I'm being thrown the following error : "oracle.net.ns.NetException: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch".

This is my JSP PAGE:

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Bid Form</title>
</head>
<body style="background:color=LightGreen">


<form action="BidInsert" method="post">

<table border=1 align="center">
<tr>
<th>Bid Number</th>
<td><input type="text"  name="bid_no"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Amount</th>
<td><input type="text"  name="amount"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>User Id</th>
<td><input type="text"  name="u_id"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Listing Id</th>
<td><input type="text"  name="l_id"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Time stamp Info</th>
<td><input type="text"  name="timestampinfo" size=50></td>
</tr>

</table>
<center>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</center>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Servlet:

```js
package Serve;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class BidInsert
 */
public class BidInsert extends HttpServlet {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public BidInsert() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
 /**
  * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  */
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  
  
  PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
  response.setContentType("text/html");
  
  String bn,a,ui,li, tsi;
  bn=request.getParameter("bid_no").toString();
  a=request.getParameter("amount").toString();
  ui=request.getParameter("u_id").toString();
  li=request.getParameter("l_id").toString();
  tsi=request.getParameter("timestampinfo");
  
  try {
   Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@apollo.vse.gmu.edu:1521:ite10g","","");
   String sql="insert into Bid values('"+bn+"','"+a+"','"+ui+"','"+li+"','"+tsi+"')";
   PreparedStatement ps=c.prepareStatement(sql);
   ps.executeUpdate(sql);
   out.println("Data Inserted successfully");
   
  } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  if(out.checkError()==false)
  {
   out.println(" <input type=\"button\"  value=\"Check Database\"  onClick=\"window.location.href('Database contents.jsp')\"> ");
  }
 }

}
```

I've omitted the username & password of the database intentionally.Is there are any specific data type to be used to take timestamp values?.Please suggest if any. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For a start consider using a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) (or similar) to avoid create sql insert strings - which are open to sql injection attacks.

Secondly it looks like the `time` info should be inserted as a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE`, so you need to convert the `String` into a `Date` using SimpleDateFormat

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Search SO and you can find thousands of examples

Comment: while most of your explanation makes lot of sense I'm still unable to figure out what exactly you want me to do, I'm a newbie to Web-development.. It will be a great help if you could share some code for the edits you've mentioned..

Comment: If you search you can find something like http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: and for setting time https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-insert-timestamp-value-in-preparedstatement/

Comment: It will be a great help if you could show your apprecaition